# "AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched" when using only 1 GET

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I'm getting this error even though I only have one GET on the page. So I'm thoroughly confused.

Here's what the whole login page looks like:

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
private UserAuthenticationService _userAuthenticationService { get; set; }
private ClaimService _claimService { get; set; }

public LoginModel(UserAuthenticationService userAuthenticationService, ClaimService claimService)
{
    _userAuthenticationService = userAuthenticationService;
    _claimService = claimService;
}

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    var user = _userAuthenticationService.Login();
    if (user == null)
    {
        //TODO: Login failed
    }
    else
    {
        var claims = _claimService.GetClaimsFromUserModel(user);
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(6),
            IsPersistent = true,
        };
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), authProperties);
    }
}
```

And here's the error. I only have one OnGet, so I don't know why it's saying there are multiple. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: is that the only method in the PageModel?

Comment: @Nkosi Correct. That's all of the code in the PageModel.

Comment: Do you have any controllers that could be causing the conflict?

Comment: I would suggest refactoring the Page action to `public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()` and have it return a page ie `return Page();`

Comment: @Nkosi No controllers. Just checked to make sure. I'll try your suggestion, but I hadn't bothered previously as it's a login page and completion of the login redirects automatically. But, I'll have to add it eventually when I get around to the login failed code.

Comment: The error message is a little ambiguous in Razor Pages. It refers to multiple attribute routes with the same template, not the handler methods themselves. However, the framework should not have built duplicate route templates for the same file, which is what it looks like has happened. I'd be tempted to log this as a potential bug on GitHub - unless you have overridden routing somewhere in the application.

Comment: @MikeBrind Oh. So, I have two Index pages in the project. But they have different routes. One is /Index and the other, /Request/Index. Could that be causing the issue?

Comment: No. You would get that error if you had _Request.cshtml_ in the _Pages_ folder, and a folder named _Request_ with an Index page in it. But the list of offending pages  in the error message would be `/Request` and `/Request/Index`, not `/Request` and `/Request`. I've tried a number of different ways to generate the same error message as yours (where the page names are the same) but I haven't been able to replicate it. Yet.